# How to loop through a list of dictionaires in another file on a block code on an html file?

Tags: python, html, django

This is kinda hard to explain. I'm building a web app using Django and I created a template in which a for loop loops through a list of dictionaires on the views.py file. Then when I run the website is a blank page.

I'm using PyCharms and I've tried to inject a language on the block of code, Python and Html, but when injecting python it says that list is not defined and when using Html the website is just blank. If I don't inject a language it says that there is a typo on the word endfor.

```
#views.py file
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

posts = [
   {
       "author": "Telmo Antunes",
       "title": "Blog post 1",
       "content": "First Post Content",
       "date_posted": "September 9th, 2019"},
    {
        'author': "Telmo Antunes",
        'title': "Blog post 2",
        'content': "2nd Post Content",
        'date_posted': "September 9th, 2019"}
]


def home(request):
    context = {
        'post': posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)

#template
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Django Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for post in posts %}
   <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
   <p>By {{ post.author }} on {{ post.date_posted }}</p>
   <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting the output on the website to be

Blog post 1
By Telmo Antunes on September 9th, 2019
First Post Content

Blog post 2
By Telmo Antunes on September 9th, 2019
2nd Post Content

Comment: please share the entire view function, and the actual output you see on the page. The first thing I would check is whether you're actually sending that data to the template under the name `posts`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond i edited the post, the page is just blank and the source looks like this 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Django Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>

Comment: Thanks. You've made a typo: `'post': posts` should be `'posts': posts`

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks it works now.